# Apache Flink Stateful Functions Remote Module Update

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

How can I update module.yaml dynamically? For example I want to add new remote function so I have to update module.yaml file. Should I stop/start flink cluster to update module.yaml? What is true approach for use case? Updating or existing remote function job is fine. Because rolling update is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, indeed the way to modify a module.yaml would be to restart the Flink cluster, but the stateful functions community is working on removing that limitation in future releases.